# web.config URL Rewrite Causing Server Error

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, azure

A while ago, I made a URL shortener in XAMPP, which used a .htaccess file to redirect to the index.php file with the URL code. It worked fine in XAMPP, but now I am publishing it in Azure, and ran into trouble. I did some research, and discovered that I needed to convert it to a web.config file because Azure doesn't recognize .htaccess files. I found a couple of converters online (Which both gave me the same code), and when I uploaded the file, it created a server error which prevented all pages from loading.

Here is the code for the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And here is the code I was given for the web.config file:

```
<rule name="rule 1s" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*)"  />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?url={R:1}"  appendQueryString="true"  />
</rule>
```

I'm not overly familiar with server files like this, which is why I tried converters, so I am at a loss here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is that your whole web.config or is there more to it?

Comment: That is it. I've never done anything with web.config, so I assumed that the converter gave me what I needed. Is something missing?

Comment: I haven't worked with it in a while. I think you need a parent `<rules>` around it though. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module If you have access to the IIS manager there is an interface in there to manage these.

Comment: Adding the parent rules tag didn't fix it. Unfortunately I don't have access to the IIS manager. Or at least I don't think I do.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? If you execute the path on the hosting machine it used to give more detailed error messages.